# Assigning base data from derived class with move produces an error

Tags: c++

I am new to the new feature of C++ such as moving semantic (moving constructor and moving assignment operator). The code below produces an error in IDE as follows.

[image]

How to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class HeavyData {};

class Base
{
protected:
    HeavyData data;

public:
    Base(HeavyData data) :data{ data } {}
    Base(Base const&& src) :data{ move(src.data) } {}

    Base& operator = (Base const&& rhs)
    {
        this->data = move(rhs.data);
        return *this;
    }
};

class  Derived : public Base
{
private:
    HeavyData extra;
public:
    Derived(HeavyData data, HeavyData extra) :
        extra{ extra }, Base(data) {}
    Derived(Derived const&& src) :
        extra{ move(src.extra) }, data{ move(src.data) }  {}

    Derived& operator = (Derived const&& rhs)
    {
        this->data = move(rhs.data);
        this->extra = move(rhs.extra);
        return *this;
    }
};
void main()
{
    HeavyData data, extra;
    Derived d1(data, extra);
    Derived d2 = move(d1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't initialize base-class data in the derived class's constructor. Invoke the base class constructor first, then your derived class's data.

```cpp
Derived(Derived const &&src) :
  Base(std::move(src)), extra{std::move(src.extra)} ()
```

Comment: Sorry, please show me the code.

Comment: @WissenMachtFrei I've edited the answer to provide sample code.

Comment: @AdrianMole Quite right, thanks. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr;You need to call base class constructor.

Since base class should be initialized before derived class, base class members should be initialized during base class constuction. You cannot affect base class members creation from the derived class, but you can call base class constructor like this:

```
 Derived(Derived const&& src) :
        Base(move(src.data)),
        extra{ move(src.extra) }{}
```

Edit: delegating -> base class

Comment: @JaMiT you're completely right. I've edited the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
Derived(Derived const&& src) : 
    Base(std::move(src.data)), 
    extra{ move(src.extra) }
{}
```

Comment: In my understanding, protected data member in base class must be visible in the derived class.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the fact that `data` is `protected`! You can't initialize a base-class member in a derived class using an initializer list ... you have to do it in the *body* of the constructor.

Comment: Changing `protected` to `public` does not solve the problem. I just tried it.

Comment: @WissenMachtFrei yeah fixed it

Comment: Why does this work? Code-only answers rarely explain anything.